# I have a problem with IOS XIOBASE and XOLCUM

Tags: c++

my utils file for my snake game

```cpp
typedef char s8;
typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef short s16;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef int s32;
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef long long s64;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

#define global_variable static
#define internal static

inline int
clamp(int min, int val, int max) {
    if (val < min) return min;
    if (val > max) return max;
    return val;
}
```

I think the problem is with the internal but I don't know what precisely is the problem.
I tried removing the internal and replacing it with static but the same problem persists.
I have to mention that this may be a bad post but this is my first time so do acknowledge it.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np3Rx.png)

This is one of the problems for example this is from Xiobase

```cpp
template <class _Dummy>
class _Iosb { // define templatized bitmask/enumerated types, instantiate on demand
public:
    enum _Fmtflags { // constants for formatting options
        _Fmtmask = 0xffff,
        _Fmtzero = 0
    };

    static constexpr int skipws     = 0x0001;
    static constexpr int unitbuf    = 0x0002;
    static constexpr int uppercase  = 0x0004;
    static constexpr int showbase   = 0x0008;
    static constexpr int showpoint  = 0x0010;
    static constexpr int showpos    = 0x0020;
    static constexpr int left       = 0x0040;
    static constexpr int right      = 0x0080;
    static constexpr int internal   = 0x0100;
    static constexpr int dec        = 0x0200;
    static constexpr int oct        = 0x0400;
    static constexpr int hex        = 0x0800;
    static constexpr int scientific = 0x1000;
    static constexpr int fixed      = 0x2000;

    static constexpr int hexfloat = 0x3000; // TRANSITION, ABI, GH-3296

    static constexpr int boolalpha   = 0x4000;
    static constexpr int adjustfield = left | right | internal;
    static constexpr int basefield   = dec | oct | hex;
    static constexpr int floatfield  = scientific | fixed;
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual text of the errors from the Output Tab and not the Errors List. The output tab is in a better format and is in proper file order.

Comment: *I tried removing the internal and replacing it with static but the same problem persists* Ask another question about this one. What you have shown is wrong for the reasons outlined in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std` already has a member called `internal`. Your `#define` replaces the word with `static`, which is illegal as a variable name.

For example:

```
static constexpr int internal   = 0x0100;
```

becomes

```
static constexpr int static   = 0x0100;
```

Likewise, the `xlocnum` header accesses the `internal` field as `ios_base::internal` , which becomes `ios_base::static`.

Change the name of `internal` to something else. If you really want to mark stuff as internal, make it an attribute instead. (`[[internal]]`) Or add a comment.

Comment: Ahhhh. The classic macro footgun injury.